# Different variable name from querystring

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My controller has an object as parameter

```
Function Search(ByVal model As ItemSearchModel) As ActionResult
```

Which look something like this

```
Public Class ItemSearchModel

    Public Property SearchQuery As String
```

And, as you can imagine, the url will look this like

```
/Search?SearchQuery=test
```

I want to change the query string to have a small variable, sort of like

```
/Search?s=test
```

Is there a built-in way I could keep the same variable name in my class? Something like

```
Public Class ItemSearchModel

    <QueryString(Name:="s")> _
    Public Property SearchQuery As String
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can use the [ActionParameterAlias](http://jeffreypalermo.com/blog/adding-an-alias-to-an-action-parameter-for-model-binding-in-asp-net-mvc/) package from Nuget to accomplish what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can define two properties, both pointing to the same field. Then you can access that item using either `s` or `SearchQuery` from the URL.

```
Public Class ItemSearchModel
    Private _s As String

    Public Property s() As String
        Get
            Return _s
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _s = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property SearchQuery() As String
        Get
            Return _s
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _s = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```