# How to map an Url to a controller method in WebApi?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, model-binding

I'm using the below model to bind the query string with my controller using `[FromUri]`

```
namespace MyApi.Models
{
    public class Product
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The controller action method code is

`public ActionResult ActionMethod1( [FromUri] Product product)`

The URL incoming is http://myapplication:2020/ActionMethod1/?Id=1&Cost=20

Now, internally the `Cost` in the query param should be mapped to `Price` in the `Product` class.

How can I do that ? I know I can use custom model binding but instead something like,

Is there any attribute that I can apply to the above class? Something like,

```
[BindingName("Cost")]
public decimal Price {get;set}
```

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17154834/different-variable-name-from-querystring

Comment: You can use the Bind attribute check these links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15810295/how-do-i-remap-an-mvc-action-parameter-to-another-parameter-name, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030614/action-parameter-naming